# Clustered NodeJS only changes worker on hard reload on Desktop Chrome

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm experimenting with clusters and nodejs. I have this simple server that returns the current PID of a worker. To test it, I have an Angular application that makes 100 $http.get() calls on the '/pid' endpoint (code included below).

Chrome for Desktop returns the same PID for all 100 calls in about 8 seconds on a normal load/reload. If I hard reload (ctrl + shift + r), I get 4 separate PIDS randomly in about 3 seconds. Clearly, there's a performance boost there, but I can't seem to get the same result with a standard load/reload.

I get the desired behavior in Firefox and Chrome Android.

I haven't really been able to find much about this. I don't think it's an Angular caching issue, because it works correctly on other browsers.

I tried adding a no-cache meta tag to my html, just in case, but that didn't change anthing.

I've attempted this on my computer and another, to make sure it's not something funky with my setup.

Any thoughts on what I can do to make this work correctly on chrome on every load?

### NodeJS Code

```
var express = require('express');
var cluster = require('express-cluster');
var cors = require('cors');
var fs = require('fs');
cluster(function(worker) {
    var app = express();
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.use(cors())
    app.get('/pid', function (req, res) {
        for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        //increase load with loop, to increase need for workers
        }
      res.send("" + worker.process.pid);
    });
    console.log("Worker id: " + worker.id);
    return app.listen(3009);
}, {count:4});
```

### Angular Code

```
angular.module('cluster', []).controller('mainCtrl',['$http','$scope', function($http, $scope){
    $scope.pids = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      $http.get("http://localhost:3009/pid").then(function(response) {
        $scope.pids.push(response.data);
      }, function(error) {

      });
    }
}]);
```

### Bad Output (Normal Chrome reload)

```
20990
20990
20990
20990
...
```

### Expected Output (Chrome Hard Reload/Other Browsers)

```
20817
20743
20818
20746
...
```

The HTML is just an ng-repeat on the pids array.

This is running on a EC2 instance with only 1 core, on a MEAN Bitnami stack.